# How do I secure data in ARM template to pass to DSC compilation resource?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

My DSC resource currently accept `string` as input parameter and when I do compilation via ARM template all this information is available in clear text all over the place. 
What would be the appropriate method to securely compile MOF resource in Azure Automation via ARM template? Information is stored in Azure KeyVault.

```
 {
              "name": "[guid(resourceGroup().id, deployment().name)]",
              "type": "Compilationjobs",
              "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
              "tags": {},
              "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('AutomationAccountName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('AutomationAccountName'),'/Configurations/swarmmanager')]"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "configuration": {
                  "name": "swarmmanager"

                },
                "parameters": {
                    "privateKey": "[parameters('privatekey')]",
                    "serverCert": "[parameters('serverCert')]",
                    "CACert": "[parameters('CACert')]"
                }

              }
            }
 "parameters": {
    "privateKey": { "type": "securestring" },
    "serverCert": { "type": "securestring" },
```

[image]

Comment: I pass this information from KeyVault via parameter currently directly to compilationjob but it ends up all over the place in Azure as result

Comment: posted example in question. Parameters themselves are of `securestring` in ARM temlate

Comment: Like I said I've never done this, can you try adjusting your runbook so that input parameters are `securestring` as well? because the documentation suggests you can do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-input-parameters#configure-input-parameters

Comment: yes, input parameters themselves are already `securestring`

Comment: i'm afraid I cant help in this case :(

Comment: Не проблема, оказывается вот как это полагается делать https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1e1be898-7ed4-4386-a8b4-6411a9ae8163/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-azure-dsc-extension-while-using-azure-automation?forum=azureautomation

Comment: ah, so offload it, okay, thanks